# JQuery validation for treeview node

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, fancytree

In mootool window i have treeview(used fancy tree plugin) which need to be validated on click of 'save' button. The validation is simple required field (user need to select atleast one node).
I have attached the code which i have tired.

```
jQuery(function ($) {   

$("#form2").validate({

    rules: {
        txtUserName: "required",
        SGITree: "required"
        },

    messages: {
        txtUserName: "Please enter first Name",
        SGITree: "Please select your tree node"
        }
    });

});    

//JQuery code for creatingtree 

$("#ADD").live("click", function (e) {
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
    buttons: buttonsConfigSave,
    title: '@Resources.Text.ResourceManager.GetString("_PopUpAdd")',
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 600,
    width: 700,
    cache: false,

    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('#txtname').val('');
        $('select[name="TipoSGITree"] option:selected').attr("selected", null);
        var nodeTree1 = $("#tree1").fancytree("getActiveNode");
        if (nodeTree1 != null)
        {                     
            $("#tree1").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodeTree1.key).setActive(false);
                 $("#tree1").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodeTree1.key).setFocus(false);                                            
        }
        var nodeTree2 = $("#tree2").fancytree("getActiveNode");                  
        if (nodeTree2 != null) {
            alert(nodeTree2.key);

       $("#tree2").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodeTree2.key).setActive(false);

       $("#tree2").fancytree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodeTree2.key).setFocus(false);
        }                  
        $(this).load(url);
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
});
$("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
return false;
});
```

the tree looks as below

process1
    sub-process1.1
    sub-process1.2
        sub-process1.1.1
sub-process2
    sub-process2.1
sub-process3
    sub-process3.1
    sub-process3.2
    sub-process3.3
    sub-process3.4
        sub-process3.4.1
sub-process5

Required field is working for textbox but not for tree. Any kind of help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of element is `SGITree`?  You can only validate `select`, `textarea` and and the various `input` types.  Where is the relevant HTML?  You are expected to show us a complete, yet concise example.

Comment: What does `MooTools` have to do with any of this?

Comment: Hi Sparky, Mootool is like a popup window. SGITree is normal tree structure with nodes and subnodes (no checkbox or radio button). to create tree structure im using fancy tree plugin. i have added the JQuery code for creating fancyTree.

Comment: My answer is still valid.  **You cannot use jQuery Validate on the tree**.  You can only validate `select`, `textarea` and and the various `input` types as long as they're contained within a `<form></form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the bottom of the issue, basically i have 1 fancy tree (say M1) in my main page and 2 fancy tree in dialog window(say DW1 & DW2). i was trying to validate the node seleceted from the DW1 but fancy tree seems to be hold the properity of fancy tree M1. Not only validation when i try to use keyboard events like 'backspace, left/right/top/bottom arrow keys'  in filter the fancy tree DW1 or DW2, the fancy tree fired the event for tree M1. As a simple solution i added `keyboard: false, // Support keyboard navigation` properity to M1 fancy tree.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED based on OP's update**

Bottom line is this cannot be done.  The suggested crude workaround is the only possible way this *might* work and that depends on a few things.

---

**Quote OP:** *"Required field is working for textbox but not for tree."*

**You cannot validate the tree nodes.  jQuery Validate can only validate `select`, `textarea` and `input` (various types) elements within a `<form></form>` container.**

Data validation means that the user is required to enter data in a particular format before the form can be submitted.  Since a tree has nothing to do with data input, how do you validate it?  What is it you're trying to achieve?

<s>After looking at the official FancyTree demo, I can only assume you want to validate the `radio` and `checkbox` items in the tree as shown in the "Embed in forms" section of the demo.</s>

Looking at the relevant source code, all we have is this...

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select 1</legend>
    <div id="tree" name="selNodes"></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select 2</legend>
    <div id="tree2" name="selNodes2"></div>
</fieldset>
```

**As you can see, there are no `select`, `textarea` or `input` elements for you to validate.**

So let's inspect the DOM to see what elements are created by the FancyTree plugin.  There is way too much markup to post here, but FancyTree dynamically creates a whole lot of nested `<ul>` lists with styled and nested `<span></span>` elements inside.  **There are absolutely no `select`, `textarea` or `input` elements within the dynamically created FancyTree markup.**

Besides, when declaring rules inside of the `rules` option of `.validate()`, the `name` attribute of a single input field (`select`, `textarea` or `input`) is the target.  You cannot just put `SGITree` in there and expect the plugin to parse through the tree looking for stuff that it should make "required".  It's a moot point as **there are no valid input elements in the tree anyway.**

*Crude workaround suggestion:*

1)  Create a custom jQuery event trigger that somehow captures the state of the FancyTree <s>checkbox/radio</s>.  <s>Although I'm not entirely sure how you'd do this as the checkbox/radio is merely constructed from `span` elements and CSS.</s>  Perhaps FancyTree already provides a built-in method for this?

2)  Whenever the state of the FancyTree <s>checkbox/radio</s> changes, copy that information into a `input type="hidden"` element also contained within your `form`.

3)  Make sure the `input type="hidden"` element contains a unique `name` and simply use that as your validation target.

4)  You'll have to use various jQuery Validate callback functions such as `errorPlacement` in order to place the validation message in a desirable location.

Comment: Many thanks Sparky for your response. I will try to resolve this in as mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: See also here http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/Fancytree.html#generateFormElements and http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-form.html

Comment: @mar10, the OP is not putting form input elements into his tree.  I think he's trying to force the user to select a node, whatever that means in the context of form validation.